# Getting CUSP working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lisp, common-lisp, cusp

I have just installed the [latest unofficial version of Cusp](http://www.sergeykolos.com/cusp/update/index.html) to go along with this [tutorial on Cusp](http://www.sergeykolos.com/cusp/intro/index.html). I do exactly as it says, verbatim, and when I save my `main.lisp` file, I see an error on the `(in-package :new-lisp1)` line which says

```
Package NEW-LISP1 not loaded
Right click on corresponding .asd file and select
Load Package
```

I right-click `new-lisp1.asd`, select "Load Package," the red error goes away, I try compiling again, and tada--it's back!

Also, another (related?) problem is that down in the REPL, I keep seeing that I am disconnected from SBCL, and I keep trying to reconnect. Basically, the window looks like these lines repeated over and over:

```
Reconnecting...done.
"You are running SBCL 1.0.8.48 via Cusp 0.9.375"
Disconnected
```

What can I do to fix these problems? (If it is any help, I'm using Eclipse on Mac OS X)

EDIT: and I would also like to note that simply selecting "Load Package" on new-lisp1.asd generates  two more "Disconnected" messages immediately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'm still not sure what caused the problem, but I reinstalled Eclipse fresh and then manually added the older, official release of Cusp to Eclipse. Everything is working fine.

In addition, I tried installing the newer Cusp on Eclipse on the Leopard machines at school, and it works fine. So perhaps it is a problem with Snow Leopard or the Lion beta that I am currently using.